# Why are the contents inside certain divs displayed outside their boxes?

Tags: html, css

My question is that why are the contents that are supposed to be inside the red and navy div boxes are displayed outside the boxes? What makes them to move the content outside the boxes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>tester</title>
      <style>       
         div { padding: 10px; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid gray; color: white;}   
         .floated {float: left; margin: 150px; background-color: fuchsia; color: white; }       
         .pos {position: relative; background-color: red; } 
         .normal {background-color: navy; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="margin: 200px; background: green; width: 600px; height: 600px">
         <div class="floated">
            <p>Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated Floated </p>
         </div>
         <div class="pos">
            <p>Relatively positioned Relatively positionedRelatively positionedRelatively positionedRelatively positionedRelatively positionedRelatively positioned</p>
         </div>
         <div class="normal">
            <p>Normal div Normal divNormal divNormal divNormal divNormal divNormal divNormal div</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

I have tried different combinations using margin and switching the position of  elements in the code and they produce different results.

I am finding difficult to understand. Hopefully someone can explain this. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you look at the [revision of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21897175/revisions), you can see that I have fixed the formatting of the code twice for you. Please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format your question.

Comment: When I change the styles like this: 
 
<style>  
 div { padding: 10px; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid gray; color: white;} 
  
 .floated {float: left; background-color: fuchsia; color: white;}  
 .pos {position: relative; background-color: red;  } 
 .normal {background-color: navy; }
</style> 

You can see, that there are no margins specified. Still, the text on the red box goes bellow it.

Comment: My concern is that why are the background and border of the red div are in one place and the text is below that? Is not the background supposed to be applied to the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the correct answer is because of HTML/CSS Stacking Contexts. I am surprised no one even talked about Rendering Process or Stacking Contexts to help answer my question properly, rather most above answers focused on how to alleviate the problem by changing the CSS. My point was not to change the CSS to affect the display, but to get deeper understanding of what was happening. So, if anyone has problems understanding why things are displayed in odd ways, understanding Stacking Contexts might give better understanding.

Looks like some people even down voted my question, I did not see any other place to put my question, I thought stackoverflow would be nice place to put my question, so, I do not know why the down votes. However, none of the answers pointed to the right direction, so why the down votes?

Comment: I guess that your question was down-voted because the first version of your question was not as clear as the current one. Now it's clear (I've just up-voted it)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contents of a div to be confined to the size of the div that you define, you have to define it's overflow property:

```
div{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    color: white;

    overflow:none;
}
```

### Edit:

Overflow does not affect positioning. It confines the contents to fit inside the dimensions you set. What is happening is your pink div is floated, but also has a 150px margin, so all of the contents of the red and blue div are pushed outside of that margin, while the containers remain where they are.

Setting the overflow to hidden forces the contents to be inside of the container, pushing the containers outside of the margin as well.

If you want the containers to have their text inside them and be in the same orientation that they are in right now, I would suggest absolutely positioning them.

Comment: Probably you need to check the question again. Because, overflow: none, changes the position of the box also. Can you explain this behavior? Or, in my opinion it has something to do with the float. Please, try the code provided and check and see if you can understand what's going on. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Floated elements are not part of normal layout. They are drawn separately later.
DIVs are block level elements they have line break at start and end.
Your text is in p elements. They are pushed below div due to line break.

Remove div { height:200px; }, text will render inside intended boxes

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow in css div. for more infomation visit below link

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

**UPDATE:**

**My question is that why are the contents that are supposed to be inside the red and navy div boxes are displayed outside the boxes? What makes them to move the content outside the boxes?**

oops, this is not an overflow issue. sorry about that.

To make the text appear correctly inside the box:
1) add "float: left" in the .pos and .normal

```
.pos {float:left;position: relative; background-color: red; }   
.normal {float:left;background-color: navy; }
```

now the text appears inside the boxes. but the boxes position is bad.

Note: the three div (.floated,.normal,.pos) is wrapped by a div. so if you use float:left in one of them, you should use float: left too in the other div. or remove the float:left in the .floated. (This is not an absolute rule. if you have an issue with the css, just tweak it until you get what u want.)

2) To repair the boxes position: remove the margin:150px from the .floated

[image]

hope this is help

Comment: If you use overflow: hidden; it changes the position of the box too! Now, why did that happen? It's so confusing! Is this how it is supposed to work? Please explain the concept it.